# Kafka GroupAuthorizationException while trying to consume a topic

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, authorization

We are facing an issue of `GroupAuthorizationException` while consuming on a Kafka topic.
In the logs, I could see it is referring to a default consumer group.

Here is my kafkauser CR who has group defined as happy-user-consumer-group:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: happy-user-consumer
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: cluster1
spec:
  authentication:
    type: tls
  authorization:
    type: simple
    acls:
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: happy-topic
          patternType: literal
        operation: Read
        host: "*"
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: happy-topic
          patternType: literal
        operation: Describe
        host: "*"
     - resource:
          type: group
          name: happy-user-consumer-group
          patternType: literal
        operation: Read
        host: "*"
```

> Error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not
>   authorized to access group: console-consumer-4369

I am not sure where is it pointing to the console-consumer group.

Also, with the below script, I am not able to list the consumer groups. Do we have any other way to see the list of consumer groups?

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka.viswa.com:9094 --command-config /tmp/prod/consumer.properties --list
```

Need help here.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include how is your consumer configured as well please?

Answer (score 2):

The cli command you are using is correct. Maybe you don't have consumer groups to list?

So how are you consuming from the topic? Also by cli? Then you could use the script like this

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic happy-topic --from-beginning --group happy-user-consumer-group --bootstrap-server kafka.viswa.com:9094 --command-config /tmp/prod/consumer.properties
```

to force the consumer using a certain consumer-group name. That one would be the one you authorized in your kafkauser CR. When you don't specify the `--group` Kafka is using a default group name, `console-consumer-4369` in your case.

Hope this helps you, I would appreciate your feedback.

Good luck,
Stephan